# Getting wrong results NLTK and REGEX

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want to match all English words that contain
each of the letters ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’ and ‘u’ exactly once and in that
order, and that does not match any other English words from the words corpus.
So far i am able to get words with all a,e,i,o,u from the corpus but some words have the vowels appearing more than once for example i'm getting results such as 'abietineous' whereas i'm looking for only words like 'abstemious'.

Here is the snippet of my code. Please assist with fixing my RE to get those results.

```
[w for w in wordlist if re.search('[a].* [e].* [i].* [o].* [u].', w)]
```

Note: I want words containing only a,e,i,o,u - in that order and the a,e,i,o,u must only appear once. (Sorry for the spaces in my code but the format wasn't capturing my asterisks * unless i put a space)

Thanks

Comment: That's because `.` matches any character.

Comment: but doesn't the square parentheses [] limit it to 1 character?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `.*`, which matches any combination of any character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your regex matches unexpected words in that the `.` modifier matches any character. If you want to get rid of that you need to restrict the characters between the special ones. In that case, you need to use a negated character class, that will match anything except vowel sounds.

```
^[^aouie]*a[^aeoui]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Wp2I6H/2

So now you can find the expected words:

```
regex = re.compile(r'[^aouie]*a[^aeoui]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]*')
[w for w in wordlist if regex.match(w)]
```

Note that since you want to use your regex within a loop it's better to compile your regex out of the loop and use the compiled one in the loop, rather than letting python to compile the regex at each iteration. Also since the regex will match the word entirely you can use `re.match` instead of search.

Comment: Regex in the demo and here not the same?

Comment: @MYGz oops, Yeah, I think I was about to test your regex before saving ;)

Comment: @MYGz and Kasramvd Thanks to you both I was able to get it using the code: [w for w in wordlist if re.search(r'^[^aouie]*a[^aeoui]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]*$', w)] ...I am using juypter notebook for python and nltk as mandated by our university so after importing and etc, executing that code results the expected results.

Comment: @Kasramvd The regexes are cached by the re module. If you have only a small number of patterns, the won't be recompiled.

Comment: @lenz Thanks for note, I wasn't aware of that. But still since we are not sure of the exact behavior, it's better to compile the regex in such situations.

Comment: The behaviour is pretty clear, only the size of the cache isn't (but a single pattern is certainly below the threshold). I have also developed a habit of explicitly compiling patterns that are reused, but I always feel like I'm falling for the frowned-upon premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
wordlist = ['education', 'abstemious', 'automobile', 'facetious', 'regulation', 'novowel', 'afacetiousman', 'aeiou', 'aaeioou', 'aieou']
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
novowel = '[^'+''.join(vowels)+']*'
pattern = ''.join([novowel + v + '{1}' for v in vowels]) + novowel + '$'
print pattern
#[^aeiou]*a{1}[^aeiou]*e{1}[^aeiou]*i{1}[^aeiou]*o{1}[^aeiou]*u{1}[^aeiou]*$    
prog = re.compile(pattern)
print list(filter(lambda w: prog.match(w), wordlist))
# ['abstemious', 'facetious', 'aeiou']
```